# LiveCD for remote access using SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Before I create a Ubuntu Live CD which will boot up and tunnel the SSH connection somewhere remote, does anyone know of any existing Live CD's which will do this?

The basic principal is that I want to give a copy of this CD to a relative, they boot it up and hey presto I get access.

Comment: `ssh` is disabled on most live images. If you would like that, you would have to bundle at least your access key and modify the service to start. Certainly possible, but not recommended by default.

Comment: There is similar question on Unix&Linux with some good answers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43012/remote-accesible-live-distribution-aka-live-cd